# edit a file in a specific column of a splited file bash shell

Tags: arrays, bash, file, awk

I have an issue where a user gives the file, column, value, and id of the line. I am trying to change the value of the line

The format of the file is:

> F1|F2|F3|F4|F5|F6|F7|F8

My thought of doing that is reading the file and put the values of each field in an array. Then I will find the line I want to change using if and I will use `awk`

```
while IFS=$'|t' read -r -a myArray
do
 if [ $4 == ${myArray[0]} ]; then
    echo "${myArray[1]} ${myArray[2]} ${myArray[4]}"
    awk -v column="$5" -v value="$6"-F '{ ${myArray[column]} = value }'
    echo "${myArray[1]} ${myArray[2]} ${myArray[4]}"
    echo "${column} ${value}"
 fi
done < $2
```

However, when I do that nothing changes: the column and value arguments don't print anything.
Any ideas?

Comment: Every time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. Read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for more background and read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt give too much information. Assume you want to change specific column which field2 is `F2`  you can do as below:

1. `$2=="F2"` is checking field 2 is matching your specific string.
2. `$2="Hello"` is assigning "Hello" to field 2
3. `$1=$1` reassign the whole record(line)
4. `print` print out the whole record

`awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"} ($2=="F2"){$2="Hello";$1=$1; print}'  sample.csv`

See my example:

```
$cat sample.csv                                                                                    
F1|F2|F3|F4|F5|F6|F7|F8

$awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"} ($2=="F2"){$2="Hello";$1=$1; print}'  sample.csv                        
F1|Hello|F3|F4|F5|F6|F7|F8
```